# static method returns value to all variables

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently facing the following problem on my java code.I've been trying to call the method trHead() which gets as parameter an arraylist and removes the last 3 items of the list and then returns it.The problem is that when i run my code and call the trHead() method for arraylist A ,seems to work just fine but in reality it alters not only arraylist A but also arraylist B without even calling it for arraylist B.

My code is the following :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class S1Calculation {

private static final int δ = 30;
private static final double ε = 0.9;
private int LCSScount = 0;  

    //Calculate the LCSS for any two trajectories
    public int LCSS(ArrayList<Double> A, ArrayList<Double> B , ArrayList<Integer> tA , ArrayList<Integer> tB) {


        if((A.size()==0) || (B.size()==0)) {
            return LCSScount;
        }

        if((Math.abs(A.get(A.size()-1)-B.get(B.size()-1))<ε) && (Math.abs(A.get(A.size()-2)-B.get(B.size()-2))<ε) && (Math.abs(A.get(A.size()-3)-B.get(B.size()-3))<ε) && (Math.abs(tA.get(tA.size()-1)-tB.get(tB.size()-1))<=δ)){
            ArrayList<Double> tmpA = new ArrayList<Double>();
            ArrayList<Double> tmpB = new ArrayList<Double>();
            ArrayList<Integer> tmptA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> tmptB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            System.out.println(A.size());
            System.out.println(B.size());
            tmpA = trHead(A);
            System.out.println(A.size());
            System.out.println(B.size());
            tmpB = trHead(B);
            System.out.println(A.size());
            System.out.println(B.size());
            tmptA = tmHead(tA);
            tmptB = tmHead(tB);
            System.out.println("yes");
            return (1+LCSS(tmpA,tmpB,tmptA,tmptB));
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Double> trHead(ArrayList<Double> Array) {
        System.out.println("im in");
        Array.remove(Array.size() -1);
        Array.remove(Array.size() -1);
        Array.remove(Array.size() -1);
        return Array;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> tmHead(ArrayList<Integer> Times){
        Times.remove(Times.size()-1);
        return Times;
    }
}
```

Also my main is the following :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    //Parse some csv files and insert them in a 2 dimensional arraylist
    File dir = new File("\\Path\\");
    List<ArrayList<Double>> Trajectories = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> Timestamps = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        Trajectory tr1 = new Trajectory(file);
        Trajectories.add(tr1.getTrajectory());
        Timestamps.add(tr1.getTimestamp());
    }
    //Call LCSS method for 4 arraylists (csv files)
    int FinalLCSS = new S1Calculation().LCSS(Trajectories.get(0),Trajectories.get(0),Timestamps.get(0),Timestamps.get(0));
```

Notice that i'm calling the LCSS for the same csv file meaning that the arraylists A and B that are being passes to the LCSS method contain the same values.Same goes for tA and tB.

When i run this i get the following results :
[image] 
[image]

As you can see the the method trHead is called for the arraylist A but the size of arraylist B is also affected.Any hep would be appreciated!

Comment: You call it with the same object reference for both `A` and `B`. So when you change it, the object is changed, so all references to it show the same. If you don't want it to change, you should make a copy.

Comment: In your `main` you call `int FinalLCSS = new S1Calculation().LCSS(Trajectories.get(0),Trajectories.get(0) ...`. You use the same reference for `A` and `B` in your method. That means, if you alter `A` you automatically alter `B`. You need to make a copy for the element returned by `Trajectories.get(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java passes objects by reference.

In the call `LCSS(Trajectories.get(0),Trajectories.get(0),...)` the arguments `ArrayList<Double> A` and `ArrayList<Double> B` end up referencing (pointing to) the same object, the object located at `Trajectories` position `0`.

If you want to work with separate objects you need to make a copy.

```
ArrayList<Double> tmpA = new ArrayList<>(A);
ArrayList<Double> tmpB = new ArrayList<>(B);
```

Now `tmpA` and `tmpB` will contain copies of `A` and `B` and will be different even if `A` and `B` is the same.